# Dynamic List of lists in Java

Tags: java, arrays, list, arraylist

I want to read a file which has the following information:

```
4 //no. of machines 
1,3,6,1 //timings for machine 1
1,3,6,1 //timings for machine 2
1,3,6,1 //timings for machine 3
1,3,6,1 //timings for machine 4
2,4,8,10 //cost for machine 1
2,4,8,10 //cost for machine 2
2,4,8,10 //cost for machine 3
2,4,8,10 //cost for machine 4
```

The no. of timing arrays and cost arrays depends on the no. of machines. An element in index 'i' of timing array is associated with the same index in cost array. For example, timing 1 for machine 1 incurs cost of 2, and timing 3 costs 4. Can anyone please suggest what data structure would be perfect for this scenario and how should I proceed with it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `int data[N][2][4]` for N machines `data[n][0]` is the timings for n, `data[n][1]` is the costs.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a Map to define the relationship between `timing` and `cost`. Alternatively you can have a class TimeCost for time cost relationship.

```
public class TimeCost{
     private Integer time;
     private Integer cost;
}

public class Machine{
     // private Map<Integer,Integer> timeCost; //possible alternative
     private List<TimeCost> timeCost;
}
```

Comment: Map is a bad idea since you'll lose the ordering, and you will not be able to store multiple records for the same timing. Your alternative is much better.

Comment: And to complete your answer, if you read the whole file, you need a List of Machines.

Comment: Timings are not unique, so you can't index by them!

Answer (score 2):

First, you should probably use a `Pair` to conserve the relationship between a timing and a cost:

```
class Pair {
    int timing;
    int cost;
}
```

Then, I'm assuming you don't receive information about how many pieces of timing/cost you get, so you'll have to use an `ArrayList` to represent a machine's information:

```
class Machine {
    ArrayList<Pair> timingAndCost;
}
```

Then, since the number of machines is specified for you, use a fixed-size array to store the machines:

```
Machine[] machines = new Machine[numberOfMachines];
```

If you're considering just storing the `ArrayList`s in an array, like this:

```
ArrayList<Pair>[] machines = new ArrayList<Pair>[numberOfMachines];
```

It doesn't work, because Java doesn't allow you to declare a generic array. But if you really don't like to have the `Machine` class, then you can just use an `ArrayList` to store the `ArrayList<Pair>`:

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<Pair>> machines = new ArrayList<>(numberOfMachines);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import java.util.ArrayList;



class DaMachine {
    private final int   mMachineIndex;
    private final int[] mTimings;
    private final int[] mCosts;

    public DaMachine(final int pMachineIndex, final int[] pTimings, final int[] pCosts) {
        mMachineIndex = pMachineIndex;
        mTimings = pTimings;
        mCosts = pCosts;
    }

    @Override public String toString() {
        final StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 0; i < mTimings.length; i++) {
            sb.append(mTimings[i] + ":" + mCosts[i] + " ");
        }
        return "Machine [#" + mMachineIndex + ": " + sb + "]";
    }
}



class CrazyFile {
    static public String CRAZY = "4 //no. of machines \r\n" + //
            "1,3,6,1 //timings for machine 1\r\n" + //
            "1,3,6,1 //timings for machine 2\r\n" + //
            "1,3,6,1 //timings for machine 3\r\n" + //
            "1,3,6,11 //timings for machine 4\r\n" + //
            "2,4,8,10 //cost for machine 1\r\n" + //
            "2,4,8,10 //cost for machine 2\r\n" + //
            "2,4,8,10 //cost for machine 3\r\n" + //
            "2,4,8,111 //cost for machine 4";
}



public class ReadCrazyFile {
    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        final String[] lines = CrazyFile.CRAZY.replace("\r\n", "\n").replace("\r", "\n").split("\n");

        final int numberOfMachines = Integer.parseInt(cleanString(lines[0]));
        final ArrayList<String> timingStrings = new ArrayList<>(numberOfMachines);
        final ArrayList<String> costStrings = new ArrayList<>(numberOfMachines);
        int offset = 1;

        // add timings
        for (int relIndex = 0; relIndex < numberOfMachines; relIndex++) {
            timingStrings.add(cleanString(lines[offset + relIndex]));
        }
        offset += numberOfMachines;

        // add costs
        for (int relIndex = 0; relIndex < numberOfMachines; relIndex++) {
            costStrings.add(cleanString(lines[offset + relIndex]));
        }
        offset += numberOfMachines; // not necessary unless used later

        // convert into objects
        final ArrayList<DaMachine> machines = new ArrayList<>(numberOfMachines);
        for (int machineIndex = 0; machineIndex < timingStrings.size(); machineIndex++) {
            final String timingString = timingStrings.get(machineIndex);
            final String costsString = costStrings.get(machineIndex);
            final int[] timings = convertToIntArr(timingString);
            final int[] costs = convertToIntArr(costsString);
            final DaMachine terminator = new DaMachine(machineIndex, timings, costs);
            machines.add(terminator);
        }

        for (final DaMachine m : machines) {
            System.out.println("" + m);
        }
    }

    static private String cleanString(final String pString) {
        return pString.split("//")[0].trim();
    }

    static private int[] convertToIntArr(final String pTimingString) {
        final String[] words = pTimingString.split(",");
        final int[] ret = new int[words.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
            ret[i] = Integer.parseInt(words[i].trim());
        }
        return ret;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the structure that you need to resolve the issue.

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> listOLists = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>();
ArrayList<Integer> list1= new ArrayList<Integer>();

list1.add(4);
listOLists.add(list1)

ArrayList<Integer> list2= new ArrayList<Integer>();
list2.add(1);
list2.add(3);
list2.add(6);
list2.add(1);
listOLists.add(list2);

ArrayList<Integer> list3= new ArrayList<Integer>();
list3.add(1);
list3.add(3);
list3.add(6);
list3.add(1);
listOLists.add(list3);
```

Like this wise you can proceed. Its just a rough idea please optimize this code according to your need.

Comment: meaningful names are very important in programing, list1, list2 - that tells nothing about what's inside... I understand this is to tell the general concept though